# Should lambda in java be allowed to call nonexistent method?

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda

With this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
        list.stream().filter((e) -> e instanceof Integer.getClass()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // Never prints out
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

The filter statement calls `Integer.getClass()`, which should show a compiler error message: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object`. Eclipse does not show any errors, and the `System.out.println(list)` never runs. Running with the debugger (in Eclipse) shows that the `list.stream()` line, and all lines after, are skipped.

Additionally, the lines `import java.util.stream.Collectors` and `List<Integer> list = ...` are highlighted as not being used. Adding a line with `Integer.getClass()` above the `list.stream()` line shows a compiler error with the statment `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object` only at that line.

Compiling the java file with `javac Test.java` from the command line gives an error: `Test.java:10: error: ')' expected` at `Integer.getClass()`'s first parenthesis.

I am confused at what is happening here, as I would 1. expect Eclipse to show a compiler error, and/or 2. throw an error, instead of appearing to execute normally and skipping code lines.

Comment: You want `e instanceof Integer`.  The return value of `getClass()` would be of type `Class<?>`, and the integers would never be instances of them, so false would always be returned, so the filter would drop all items.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I understand that that would be the correct code, but I am more curious as to why Eclipse allows me to run the line at all, and then why the debugger shows it skipping the line.

Comment: Yeah, the eclipse compiler has some problems with lambdas.

Comment: I installed Eclipse, and it does run normally with no errors, it's Eclipse related problem.

Comment: I once tried to modify a [minecraft mod](https://github.com/CyclopsMC/IntegratedDynamics/) and got a compile error in an lambda, where the Eclipse compiler thinks it is a stream of `Object`s, not some other class.

Answer (score 2):

That's purely an issue in Eclipse IDE itself. I am using intellij idea and i get errors straight away. See screenshot below:

[image]

Anyways the correct code should be :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
        list.stream()
                .filter(e ->
                        e instanceof Integer
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // It now prints out :)
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup! I know! The problem faced  by SO was that his code was able to run in eclipse with this code without any error. Secondly `instanceof` don't need a `Clazz.class` or `Clazz.getClass()`.

Comment: Sure it doesn't I simply stated `getClass()` is used with `instances` and `.class` WOULD be used with classes if necessary and I stated `but anyhow this is completely unnecessary`.

Comment: @prsvr please don't delete  your comments as it spoils the discussion.

Comment: Intellij shows an error at `getClass())).collect` what is closer, but also nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, according to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/), the **Eclipse Java IDE should show a compile error at `e instanceof Integer.getClass()`**.

[15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> It is a compile-time error if the *ReferenceType* mentioned after the
>   instanceof operator does not denote a reference type that is reifiable
>   ([§4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7)).

Please [report this bug to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=Core).